# How can I implement searching with vuejs and bootstrap-vue's form-input and form-checkbox components?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a code here:

```html
<b-form-input v-model="search" placeholder="Search"></b-form-input>
<b-form-checkbox-group v-model="selected" :options="options" stacked></b-form-checkbox-group>
```

```js
search: null,
selected: [],
options: [
  {
    value: 'apple',
    text: 'Apple'
  },
  {
    value: 'orange',
    text: 'Orange'
  },
  {
    value: 'grape',
    text: 'Grape'
  }
],
```

I want to create a simple search regarding the code above.

**From this:**
[image]

**To this:**
[image]

I am using https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example) with a [javascript array filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) for that. Like:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      options: [
        {
          value: 'apple',
          text: 'Apple',
        },
        {
          value: 'orange',
          text: 'Orange',
        },
        {
          value: 'grape',
          text: 'Grape',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredOptions() {
      return this.options.filter((option) =>
        option.value.includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      )
    },
  },
}
```

[You can find a working example here](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqVUstOwzAQ/JVVLk0kSO8hrYQ4cEHqgSPhYOJta+Halu2Eoij/jh9Ja6BS1ZXy8HpmduzdIXtUquw7zKqstnhQnFhcNwLgFYlu9xXUTKjOQn9/kBT5qslM2Giydf2hYTm9PcM/NWW9w26ldkipLJMCmIAt4xY10k3ImCaD6hO/T5CyJ7xDJ+klAIYBprzFox3HILx0ym6/XiYu3dK0minriXhUUluguCUdtzB4FiWW5EX8B9BoOy3mlY94lgoWi7tzMtY2Fbydc3Mk3DSCfydDlOKYaqXhD+Mw7sId5j9kvEC72YDUROyuOdhE0GULN5fcaaKuVXwOmAsFf6feJ5WQjvfRyoMbP6TVbOPPKJ27m3TY7pkppzaWkZDncV3Aaj1PVzhByUTLO4omD6w4EaWVL/IL9RMxmBdF8ZD6akT4+lk8TV8jsvEHowrpFQ==), without using your bootstrap component.

Replace the `options` by `filteredOptions` and that probably should work:

```html
<b-form-checkbox-group v-model="selected" :options="filteredOptions" stacked></b-form-checkbox-group>
```